# Get values from a JList to seperate textboxes

Tags: java, textbox, jlist, tostring, selectedvalue

I have a database and a java application.
My java application connects to the database and through a query I get the return:

```
[peter, 12, streetname1, cityname1]
```

I cast the data to a JList(say data_List). How do I make it that all the data goes into seperate textboxes?
So
Textbox 1 would be peter
Textbox 2 would be 12
Textbox 3 would be streetname 1
Textbox 4 wiyld be cityname 1

If I use `textbox1.setText(data_list.getSelectedValue().toSTring))` all my values go to the first textbox.

Is there a way to get the values into separate textboxes?

Comment: Most folks I know would display this kind of data in a JTable, not a JList.

Comment: Is it possible to then go something like : textbox1.setText(cell(0,0));?

Comment: Are you replying to my comment? If so, your reply confuses me since a JTable does not work that way at all. I suggest that you have a look at the JTable tutorial. Google can help you find this.